# read -p : input path

Tags: scripts, input

Using

```
read -p "input variable: " variable
```

in a Linux shell script poses several problems when `variable` is a path:

1. environment variables are taken as text, e.g. `$PROJECT/subdir`
2. home directory prefix `~` also is taken as text
3. path autocompletion does not work with `read -p`

How to conveniently input paths into a Linux shell script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since interpretation of `$variable` and `~` are done by the shell, you could simply have the shell do the work. That is:

```
read -p "input variable: " variable
variable="$(eval echo $variable)"
```